# iOS exception: NSUnknownKeyException: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key " after connection xib to a ViewController as owner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create a XIB with a ViewController.
So I created the XIB (named Test.xib) with a ViewController and set the File's Owner custom class to the ViewController (named: TestViewController).

So far so good. I can load the xib in another view controller and add it as a subview like this:

```
let vc = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIViewController
vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

addChildViewController(vc)

contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

The error appears as soon as I want to create an IBOutlet from the xib in my ViewController via dragging it in the assistant editor.

I checked the other posts regarding this error, but nothing seems to explain why it's happening in this case, and I cannot resolve it with the suggested solutions.

I saw in the "Connection inspector" that the referencing outlet is linked from the StackView to "File's Owner". Is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
class YourViewClass:UIView{

       public static let nibName = "YourViewClass"
       public static let nib = YourViewClass.getNib()
       class func getNib() -> UINib {
           return UINib(nibName: YourViewClass.nibName, bundle: nil)
        }

  class func viewFromNib()-> YourViewClass {
       let nib = YourViewClass.getNib()
       return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! YourViewClass
 }    }
```

Comment: The project goes with the clean swift architecture and because of that, the view has a ViewController and several classes that go along with that (Interactor, Presenter and more). Sadly I don't think I can do these things if my XIB extends from UIView. That's the reason I want it to extend from UIViewController.

Comment: Extent from view controller also it will work.Try once.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Isn't that exactly what I'm doing already? My xib with name Test.xib has it's own ViewController file with name TestViewController, which I set as it's owner in the xib file.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, I'm stuck on it as well I'm creating a separate class like this answer suggested, every thing works fine as long as I don't add an iboutlet through the file-owner, when I do add it I get the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x600003dd4fa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contentView.'`

btw I have successfully added a xib in a sample project, it's just not working in my current project and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Updated answer, Please try now.
It's working for in all scenarios.